# GraphQL + Spring Boot: how to collect (error) metrics?

Tags: spring-boot, graphql, spring-boot-actuator, datadog, spring-micrometer

I've been working on adding monitoring metrics in our GraphQL gateway recently.

We're using [graphql-spring-boot](https://github.com/graphql-java-kickstart/graphql-spring-boot) starter for the gateway.

After reading the following documentations, I manage to send the basic graphql.timer.query.* metrics to Datadog

- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-actuators
- https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.x/actuator-api/html/#metrics
- https://github.com/graphql-java-kickstart/graphql-spring-boot#tracing-and-metrics

What I've achieved so far is, when I send a GraphQL query/mutation, I'd collect the request count and time accordingly. e.g. sending the query below

```
query HelloWorldQuery {
  greeting(
    name: "Bob"
  ) {
    message
  }
}
```

I'll see metrics `graphql.timer.query.count` / `graphql.timer.query.sum` with tags `operationName=HelloWorldQuery`

It works like perfectly, until I want to test a query with errors. I realise there is no metrics/tags related to a failed query. For example, if I the above query returns null data and some GraphQL errors, I'd still collect `graphql.timer.query.count (operationName=HelloWorldQuery)`, but there's no additional tags for me to tell there is an error for that query.

In the gateway, I have implemented a custom `GraphQLErrorHandler`, so I was thinking maybe I should add error counter (via MeterRegistry) in that class, but I am unable to get the `operationName` simply from GraphQLError type. the best I can get is error.getPath() which gives the method name (e.g. `greeting`) rather than the custom query name (`HelloWorldQuery` - to be consistent with what `graphql.timer.query.*` provides).

My question is, how to solve the above problem? 
And generally what is the best way of collecting GraphQL query metrics (including errors)?

------------------- **Update** -------------------

**2019-12-31**
I read a bit more about GraphQL Instrumentation [here](https://github.com/graphql-java/graphql-java-page/blob/master/content/documentation/v10/instrumentation.md) and checked the [MetricsInstrumentation](https://github.com/graphql-java-kickstart/graphql-spring-boot/blob/master/graphql-spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/com/oembedler/moon/graphql/boot/metrics/MetricsInstrumentation.java) implementation in graphql-spring-boot repo, the I have an idea of extending the MetricsInstrumentation class by adding error metrics there.

**2020-01-02**
I tried to ingest my CustomMetricsInstrumentation class, but with no luck. There is internal AutoConfiguration wiring, which I cannot insert my auto configuration in the middle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can override the default `TracingInstrumentation` with your own implementation. It will be picked automatically due to the @ConditionalOnMissingBean annotation in the [GraphQLInstrumentationAutoConfiguration](https://github.com/graphql-java-kickstart/graphql-spring-boot/blob/08395c9c458f00cdc68076ed4926162f063b1251/graphql-spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/com/oembedler/moon/graphql/boot/GraphQLInstrumentationAutoConfiguration.java#L45) class. Here is a simple example that adds two custom metrics: **graphql.counter.query.success** and **graphql.counter.query.error**:

```java
@Component
public class CustomMetricsInstrumentation extends TracingInstrumentation {

    private static final String QUERY_STATUS_COUNTER_METRIC_NAME = "graphql.counter.query";
    private static final String OPERATION_NAME_TAG = "operationName";
    private static final String UNKNOWN_OPERATION_NAME = "unknown";

    private MeterRegistry meterRegistry;

    public CustomMetricsInstrumentation(MeterRegistry meterRegistry) {
        this.meterRegistry = meterRegistry;
    }

    @Override
    public CompletableFuture<ExecutionResult> instrumentExecutionResult(ExecutionResult executionResult,
                                                                        InstrumentationExecutionParameters parameters) {

        String status = CollectionUtils.isEmpty(executionResult.getErrors()) ? "success" : "error";
        String operation = parameters.getOperation() != null ? parameters.getOperation() : UNKNOWN_OPERATION_NAME;
        Collection<Tag> tags = Arrays.asList(Tag.of(OPERATION_NAME_TAG, operation));

        meterRegistry.counter(QUERY_STATUS_COUNTER_METRIC_NAME + "." + status, tags).increment();

        return super.instrumentExecutionResult(executionResult, parameters);
    }
}
```

My application.yaml, just in case:

```
graphql:
  servlet:
    tracing-enabled: true
    actuator-metrics: true
management:
  endpoint:
  metrics:
    enabled: true
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: health,metrics
```

I'm using spring-boot-starter-parent:2.2.2.RELEASE, graphql-spring-boot-starter:6.0.0

I hope it helps.

Comment: Where does the management config section come from? Is it provided by any maven package and which one? Thanks.

Comment: @KokHowTeh It comes from the Spring Boot Actuator: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-features.html

Comment: @Mafor I have done the same but in my case the operation name is always unknown?

Comment: @Mafor What would be the best approach when using Spring Boot 3 Observability?